# What's the most efficient way to copy a column of cells from one spreadsheet to another?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy one column of cells from a spreadsheet to another (append it at the bottom). The code below works, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this without a loop. Is there a faster or more efficient way of doing this?

```
function CopyToAnotherSheet() {

  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

  var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15-vXNpnzSEKzcqhBmJ_D173rwGyM7TOAZE1iL_wsf2A');
  var destSheet = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]; 

  // Get the contents of a cell in srcSheet
  var range = srcSheet.getRange("xposed!A1:A")
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      destSheet.appendRow(values[i]);
      }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the getRange() method with setValues to setValues() to set the range as the array only.
Refer this documentation for getting a clear idea [Document Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

```
function CopyToAnotherSheet() {

  var sourceSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var srcSheet = sourceSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0];

  var destinationSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15-vXNpnzSEKzcqhBmJ_D173rwGyM7TOAZE1iL_wsf2A');
  var destSheet = destinationSpreadSheet.getSheets()[0]; 

  // Get the contents of a cell in srcSheet
  var range = srcSheet.getRange("xposed!A1:A")
  var values = range.getValues();

  //returns last row of the destination sheet
  var lastRow=destSheet.getLastRow();

  //starting from the last row, it will apend the array in the column
  //getrange(num of row to start from, num of column to start from, number of rows in array to append, num of column in array to append)
  destSheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, values.length,1).setValues(values);

}
```